# Gitlab-runner with syntax error

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I recently used the docker image [gitlab/gitlab-runner:9.1.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner/) in conjunction with a gitlab container to have some CI.
An error occurs and similar support requests recommended using a different version, so I tried with `:latest` and some `:1.11` too.
Unfortunately it keeps telling me this error:

```bash
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.11.4 (5e7ba4a)
  on foo (02cdacdc)
Using Docker executor with image pretzlaw/php:7.1-apache ...
Starting service mariadb:latest ...
Pulling docker image mariadb:latest ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image pretzlaw/php:7.1-apache ...
Running on runner-02cdacdc-project-7-concurrent-0 via 9d1d33dc9212...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 7580815 QA: CI Lint
From http://idgaf.example.org/foo/bar
   7580815..affeede  develop    -> origin/develop
Checking out affeede as develop...
Skipping Git submodules setup
[: 1: [: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
[: 1: [: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2
```

Neither do I know how to debug this nor do I see any problem in my container or test script. This is the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
before_script:
  - composer install

test_7_1:
  image: pretzlaw/php:7.1-apache
  script: ls
```

It could be a problem of the container somewhere but I don't get it. Doing this manually (with the recent failed docker container) everything works fine:

```
docker container exec 68c7b5448a56 ls
bin
builds
...
```

How do I trace back the problem?
What is it all about?

It's for GitLab 9.1.1-ce.0.

Comment: Can you add your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: Also, even though you're using gitlab/gitlab-runner:9.1.0, it seems the version inside the container is 1.11.4

Comment: Thanks @Jawad . I just added the yml and added the information that I also tried other gitlab-runner versions/tags on this. Seems like I copied some output from another version.

Comment: Looks like it might be having trouble parsing `test:7.1`. Could you try with `test_7.1`?

Comment: I tried with "test_7_1" but this still fails :/

Comment: Are you linking the two containers together explicitly?

Comment: If you read something about 2 containers then this information is old. There is just one container. @MikeTung

Comment: Where is the `pretzlaw/php:7.1-apache` docker image hosted? GitLab Container Registry or Docker Hub?

Comment: Yes. Here https://hub.docker.com/r/pretzlaw/php/ @ConnorShea

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [#1550](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1550), the problem seems to be coming from the shell detection done in the `bash.go` file between [lines 16-31](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/v1.11.4/shells/bash.go#L16-31) which it is injected without newlines and thus creating the syntax error you are yourself experiencing.

Since you have a custom entrypoint in your `Dockerfile` and it looks like you have not passed quotes to the arguments of the exec [here](https://github.com/pretzlaw/docker-php/blob/master/7.0-apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L81), that's what I think is failing and should be modified.

Change it to

```
exec "${*}"
```

Comment: I recently and it worked. Thanks so much! But now it says it can't find "/home/www-data/www/sh" - this is so messed up. Dunno why it tries it with the path.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to the bug mentioned by Balthazar, try overriding the entrypoint in `.gitlab-ci.yml` as illustrated in the [GitLab docs:](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#overriding-the-entrypoint-of-an-image)

For Docker 17.06 and later:

```
image:
  name: super/sql:experimental
  entrypoint: [""]
```

For Docker 17.03 and earlier:

```
image:
  name: super/sql:experimental
  entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```